# BizTalk AS2 incomming X12 outgoing signed TA1 and 997

Tags: biztalk, actionscript-2, sign, x12

I've managed to follow the Microsoft BizTalk AS2 tutorial "Tutorial 3: AS2 Tutorial" (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb245935.aspx) to receive an X12 message over AS2 and send back a MDN, and also the X12 TA1 and 997.
I also managed to add a self-signed certificate to sign the outgoing MDN.
My problm is that I also want to sign the outgoing X12 TA1 and 997 messages.
How can that be done?

Answer (score 2):

Just configure the Send Port for AS2 with your Trading Partner.  The TA1 and 997/999 are just regular X12 messages.

Just to note, the Sender has to request a TA1, you shouldn't just send one unsolicited.

Comment: My problem is not creating the TA1 or 997. My problem is to sign them. I have requested outgoing messages to be signed, but only the MDN is signed, not the TA1 or 997.

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved. I had missed to specify "Message should be signed" in the AS2 Agreement, under Validation in the outbound part. Now I can sign outgoing MDN, TA1 and 997.